# Creationism at its best

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A relationship so justified
Sensitive in nature deemed classified
Stained the world in all aspects
Likely to start future prospects

Vandalism left still enduring
Physical marks keep alluring
A timeless art made from bone
In Rome a cephalopod you might own

Arch the enchanters wand
One which Edward would be fond
The blood runs with absolute
No matter if you are mute

---

**What is this riddle referring to?**

Comment: Wow, 5 downvotes. What is wrong with this riddle?

Comment: @randal'thor maybe, the inertia of the crowd.. :)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @Aravind Given the riddle tag, it should be obvious what the question is, but I've edited to make it clearer. Oblong, feel free to rollback if you disagree with my edit :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Thank you, the bold might be a bit to much but it makes its point well :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be:

> Bolinus Brandaris (murex) or Ink, as you can extract purple ink from the murex.

Indeed:

A relationship so justified

> It has a shell, Justified used as the format of text

Sensitive in nature deemed classified

> It's actually a animal, it reacts to stimuli

Stained the world in all aspects

> It was originally used to make purple ink

Likely to start future prospects

> The purple ink was used to dye precious fabrics, which were used by rich people during important discussions.

Vandalism left still enduring

Physical marks keep alluring

> After extracting the ink, only the dead shell remains.
>  A timeless art made from bone
>  
>  As already said, the valuable purple color was made from a shell, which can be compared to a bone.

In Rome a cephalopod you might own

> Romans were the main buyers of murex.

Arch the enchanters wand

> It alludes to the pen, used along with the ink.

One which Edward would be fond

> ( Edward Bulwer-Lytton ) who coined "the pen is mightier than the sword", also referred to the pen as an arch enchanter's wand.

The blood runs with absolute

> The ink can be considered the murex's blood.

No matter if you are mute

> Ink is mute

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> LEADERSHIP?

I got to this just by following my nose in the first verse. The OP has written [another riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5471/name-that-sandwich) with this very answer though.

*A relationship so justified*

> Many leaders consider their position as leader, and the relationship they consequently take to others, to be justified.

*Sensitive in nature deemed classified*

> Some leaders hide away and make decisions behind the scenes, so their role could be seen as classified information.

*Stained the world in all aspects*

> Certain leaders have made very bad decisions and left great stains on the world. Even today, Adolf Hitler's very name can be used as a synonym of evil.

*Likely to start future prospects*

> On the other hand, some leaders have wonderful visions of the future and make great things possible.

*Vandalism left still enduring*

> A similar reference to the 3rd line, perhaps: the wrecking decisions made by long-gone leaders still leave their marks on the world.

*Physical marks keep alluring*

> Symbols of leadership, such as crowns, sceptres, and diamonds.

*A timeless art made from bone*

> Not sure about this line.

*In Rome a cephalopod you might own*

> A reference to Roman emperors maybe. I can't see how cephalopods come into it though.

*Arch the enchanters wand

 One which Edward would be fond

 The blood runs with absolute

 No matter if you are mute*

> This is probably a reference to some fictional work involving enchanters and a character named Edward. I haven't worked this verse out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a:

> Poem

A relationship so justified

Sensitive in nature deemed classified

> Poems are more on [emotions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vK2Baco46A) so give meaning to relationships and can be classified based on 9 emotions (romance, heroism, comic, pathos, wrathful, terrifying, odious and wonderous)

Stained the world in all aspects

> poetry over time impacted world and brought changes.

Likely to start future prospects

> same as above

Vandalism left still enduring

> There are thousand cases you can find where poets were killed, there works were burnt, poetry was outlawed but still still survives.

Physical marks keep alluring

> Used as epithets or other physical forms

A timeless art made from bone

> Even after 1000s of years many poetry are there and still very effective very strong

In Rome a cephalopod you might own

> It is slippery for some

Arch the enchanters wand

> like a magic

One which Edward would be fond

> Even king Edward loved it

The blood runs with absolute

No matter if you are mute

> Even if you can not speak you can enjoys it (as still you can hear it)

Comment: Where does the list of 9 emotions come from? (not a criticism but I am intrigued)

Comment: @Relaxed , thanks for asking this question. In sanskrit these are called Rasa, here is a link on it I just found: http://www.rasas.info/ hope it helps :)